# Python 2.7.8 - Preserve root parent child relationship in a tree when unpickling the structure

Tags: python, serialization, tree, pickle

I have a tree data structure that I would like to be able to pickle and unpickle.

The problem is that when unpickling, all the children pointing to root as their parent seem to store a reference to a different address than the one of the actual root.

Both the actual root and this 'spurious' root seem to have the exact same attributes and point to the exact same children, however when following the parent relationship bottom-up, I obviously reach the incorrect root node.

I've created a compilable example [here](http://pastebin.com/83hcgib6) (apologies for the length of the code but thought this is shortest I can do to illustrate the problem).

If you imagine a structure going like this:

```
0
 - 1
 - 2
   - 3
     - 4
```

This is the output after I print the parent-child relationship of the above nodes before unpickling:

```
Node: 0 <__main__.Node instance at 0x2b112094acb0> 
Node: 1 <__main__.Node instance at 0x2b112094ac68> Parent: 0 <__main__.Node instance at 0x2b112094acb0>
Node: 2 <__main__.Node instance at 0x2b112093a680> Parent: 0 <__main__.Node instance at 0x2b112094acb0>
Node: 3 <__main__.Node instance at 0x2b112093a710> Parent: 2 <__main__.Node instance at 0x2b112093a680>
Node: 4 <__main__.Node instance at 0x2b112093a758> Parent: 3 <__main__.Node instance at 0x2b112093a710>
```

Notice how node `0` matches the address that nodes `1` and `2` point to as their parent (`0x2b112094acb0`).

However after I unpickle the data:

```
Node: 0 <__main__.Node instance at 0x2b4fefd3e7a0> 
Node: 1 <__main__.Node instance at 0x2b4fefd30ab8> Parent: 0 <__main__.Node instance at 0x2b4fefd30ef0>
Node: 2 <__main__.Node instance at 0x2b4fefd30ea8> Parent: 0 <__main__.Node instance at 0x2b4fefd30ef0>
Node: 3 <__main__.Node instance at 0x2b4fefd30a28> Parent: 2 <__main__.Node instance at 0x2b4fefd30ea8>
Node: 4 <__main__.Node instance at 0x2b4fefd307a0> Parent: 3 <__main__.Node instance at 0x2b4fefd30a28>
```

Now node `0` points to one address (`0x2b4fefd3e7a0`) and nodes `1` and `2` for their parent point to a completely different address yet still a node `0` (`0x2b4fefd30ef0`).

Is there any way to correct this in `pickle` without manually going through all the children of the root and assigning them the correct parent address?

At the moment I fix this manually, but was wondering if this is a common issue with pickle and recursive structures and if there are provisions for resolving it.

Comment: Your question makes my brain hurt.  I've tried to read it a few times, and I get sleepy half-way through each time.

Aside from that… have you tried `dill`?  It can pickle classes by serializing the class definitions instead of by reference, so you shouldn't have a reference problem.

https://github.com/uqfoundation  I'm the `dill` author.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns Hi and thanks for having a go at solving my problem. Right now I simply correct those references and it turns out not to be a big deal but I'll see if I can get our admins to install your module on our environment. I had a read through the description on git and it sounds pretty good.

Comment: On further reading… a possible way to preserve the reference structure would be to put all items 0-4 that you are pickling into a tuple, and serialize the tuple.  Then when you deserialize, the pointer relationship will hold.  (for example, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26166678/pickling-objects-that-refer-to-each-other)

Comment: @MikeMcKerns Good point, thanks, I hadn't thought about using tuples.